# Jenkins plugin list cannot be updated

Tags: centos-7, jenkins

I installed a Jenkins on my laptop, but cannot update the plug-in list. I just don't know how to further investigate it.

Here are some information:

- My laptop have a Windows system.
- I created a VirtualBox VM with CentOS7 installed.
- The VM has two network adapters: one is set as NAT (for accessing internet) 
  while the other is set as host only (for me to SSH to that VM). The default 
  route is set on the NAT adapter.
- I'm working behind my company's proxy so I set proxy information in the
  'Advance' tab of Plugin Manager of Jenkins. And when I put 
  'https://www.google.com' into 'Test URL' box and click 'Validate
  Proxy', it shows 'Success' But when I click 'Check now' at the bottom
  of the page, nothing happened and it always show 'Update information
  obtained: N/A ago'.
- I'm able to get the JSON data following the URL in 'Update Site' from my 
  VM with curl (i.e. I'm able to run this command successfully on my VM and 
  get the JSON: curl 'https://updates.jenkins.io/current/update-center.json')
- My JRE is the latest one downloaded from Oracle's official site, the version
  is 1.8.0_171 64-Bit (jre-8u171-linux-x64.rpm).
- My Jenkins is the latest one downloaded from Jenkins' official site
  (jenkins-2.107.3-1.1.noarch.rpm)

Is there any log of Jenkins that I can check for this issue?

Route on my CentOS:

```
[root@localhost ~]# ip route
default via 10.0.2.2 dev enp0s3  proto static  metric 100
10.0.2.0/24 dev enp0s3  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.2.15  metric 100
192.168.56.0/24 dev enp0s8  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.56.80  metric 100
```

The server finally displays the following exception:

```
<cycle to java.net.SocketException: Connection reset>
    Caused: javax.net.ssl.SSLException
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.MeteredStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.Reader.read(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:2001)
        at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:1980)
        at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:1957)
        at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:1907)
        at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(IOUtils.java:778)
        at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(IOUtils.java:803)
        at hudson.model.DownloadService.loadJSON(DownloadService.java:168)
    Caused: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection has been shutdown
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.checkEOF(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.available(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.available(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.MeteredStream.available(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.http.KeepAliveStream.close(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.FilterInputStream.close(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.close(Unknown Source)
        at hudson.model.DownloadService.loadJSON(DownloadService.java:176)
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readV3Record(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.MeteredStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.Reader.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:2001)
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:1980)
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:1957)
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:1907)
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(IOUtils.java:778)
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(IOUtils.java:803)
    at hudson.model.DownloadService.loadJSON(DownloadService.java:168)
    at hudson.model.UpdateSite.updateDirectlyNow(UpdateSite.java:190)
    at hudson.PluginManager.doCheckUpdatesServer(PluginManager.java:1640)
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle.invokeWithArguments(Unknown Source)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$MethodFunction.invoke(Function.java:343)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.interceptor.RequirePOST$Processor.invoke(RequirePOST.java:77)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.PreInvokeInterceptedFunction.invoke(PreInvokeInterceptedFunction.java:26)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:184)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:117)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$1.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:129)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:715)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:845)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$2.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:186)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:715)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:845)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:649)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:238)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:841)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1650)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:154)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:157)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637)
    at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
    at hudson.security.UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.java:51)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at jenkins.security.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:117)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilter(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:125)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter.doFilter(RememberMeProcessingFilter.java:142)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:271)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at jenkins.security.BasicHeaderProcessor.doFilter(BasicHeaderProcessor.java:93)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:249)
    at hudson.security.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.java:67)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:90)
    at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637)
    at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.doFilter(DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.java:30)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:533)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:524)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:190)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1595)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1253)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1564)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:166)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1155)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:564)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:317)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:279)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.Invocable.invokePreferred(Invocable.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.Invocable$InvocableExecutor.invoke(Invocable.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:294)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:199)
    at winstone.BoundedExecutorService$1.run(BoundedExecutorService.java:77)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you check the system logs at:
Jenkins | Manage Jenkins | System Log
In All Jenkins Logs, a successful attempt should should report something like:

```
Mar 27, 2019 8:49:33 AM INFO hudson.util.Retrier start
Attempt #1 to do the action check updates server
Mar 27, 2019 8:49:37 AM INFO hudson.model.UpdateSite updateData
Obtained the latest update center data file for UpdateSource default
Mar 27, 2019 8:49:40 AM INFO hudson.model.DownloadService$Downloadable load
Obtained the updated data file for hudson.tools.JDKInstaller
Mar 27, 2019 8:49:40 AM INFO hudson.util.Retrier start
Performed the action check updates server successfully at the attempt #1
```

If you see something else, consider upping the logging levels.

Also, my configured Update site is:
https://updates.jenkins.io/update-center.json